# How can I get information from the ads within a website?

Tags: text

Is there any function that identifies ads on a website?
I would like to analyze them but I do not know how by using Mathematica.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ads on a website"?

Comment: No, there is no built-in function that identified ads on a website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not currently supported